# Failed to capture a certain field from different containers out of a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script using requests to fetch data from a [webpage](https://www.abcop.org/abc-directory?searchType=facility&PostCode=10001&Radius=10). The content in that page is highly dynamic but there is an api avilable which I found out while observing network activity in dev tools. I could grab almost all the fields from each container except for the value of `DMEPOS Accredited For`. How can I capture that using requests?

Here is what I've tried with (currently it prints the name):

```
import requests
from pprint import pprint

link = 'https://www.abcop.org/mxt/FacilityApi/GetFacilities?PostCode=99999&Radius=10'

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    for item in res.json()['ResultSet']:
        print(item['org_name'])
```

Comment: Do you need any more detail in answer? Is it pretty much what you were after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DMEPOS accredited settings are indicated by flags ('0' - No, '1' - Yes) present in a different API call. In that call the organisation names and result count match for webpage link you gave. The other API call gives a different set of results.

The mappings for most of those flags (a couple are not present, are set in the response as "1", but not present on the page e.g. `amc_app_orth_off_the_shelf_flag_ext`) are present in a JavaScript file, and you can construct your own lookup to map flags to values; as seen on the webpage for DMEPOS Accredited. To construct this lookup you can regex out the JavaScript object housing the page-to-flag mappings,

[image]

then use hjson to handle the unquoted keys, and write your own function to reverse the key, value mappings. As there can be multiple values for the same key, then the value associated with the key is a list, and items with the same key are added to that list.

Then, when you make a request to the API end point which returns the listings with the flags, you can uses your lookup to return the accreditation values seen on the page.

```
import requests
import re
import hjson

def print_dmepos_accredited(item: dict):

    result = []

    print(item['org_name'])

    for k, v in item.items():

        if k in lookup:
            if isinstance(v, list):
                if any([int(i) for i in v]):
                    result.extend(lookup[k])
            else:
                if int(v):
                    result.extend(lookup[k])
    print(result)


def create_lookup(data: dict) -> dict:
    d = {}

    for k, v in data.items():
        for i in v:
            if i in d:
                d[i].append(k)
            else:
                d[i] = [k]
    # d['amc_app_orth_off_the_shelf_flag_ext'] = ['Unknown']  # not in js file
    # d['amc_app_orth_prefabricated_flag_ext'] = ['Unknown']  # not in js file

    return d


with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(
        'https://www.abcop.org/mxt/FacilityApi/GetFacilities?PostCode=10001&Radius=10').json()
    res = s.get(
        'https://www.abcop.org/ResourcePackages/ABC/modules/abc-directory/dist/main.js?v=2021-03-04T10:56:formatted').text
    data = hjson.loads(re.search(r'accredTypes:(.*?\})', res).group(1))

    lookup = create_lookup(data)

    for item in r['ResultSet']:
        print_dmepos_accredited(item)
        print()
```

Comment: Sorry @QHarr, I didn't notice that you provided a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that `DMEPOS Accredited For` in [`js` file](https://www.abcop.org/ResourcePackages/ABC/modules/abc-directory/dist/main.js), in this form :

```js
function(t){
       t.exports=JSON.parse('
              ["Orthotics","Prosthetics","Pedorthics","Assistants","Technician","Orthotic Fitting","Mastectomy","Therapeutic Shoe Fitting"]')},
function(t){
       t.exports=JSON.parse('
              ["Orthotics","Prosthetics","Pedorthics","Mastectomy","Central Fab","Ocular","DME","Pharmacy","Non-Custom Shoes"]')}
```

But I haven't really found how they load this data in website.